# Localhost Protocols are not matched

Tags: javascript, security, localhost

I am getting this error, effects my web website running on localhost, how can i work out this issue ?

Thank you.

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that error by making the protocols match (i.e. by hosting the local site over HTTPS instead of plain HTTP).

You'll then get another error because you would be trying to access a different origin, which is forbidden (who wants to visit a site which is able to open GMail in an iframe and then read their email with JavaScript and send it to the site owner?).

Cross-origin communication through frames is possible with [postMessage and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), but Google aren't going to implement their half of the JS for you.

Comment: So, what should I do ? :D

Comment: @NewPHPer — You should not try to read data from Google through an iframe. It isn't your site and they won't let you. You might be able to achieve your real goal  though some other technique, but that's an http://xyproblem.info/